# How to delete content item and ALL references to that item in Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

What is the best way to achieve this requirement: “When content item is deleted in Sitecore all references (links and referenced field) to that item should be removed.”

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you delete an item in Sitecore, it will alert you to the fact that it's referenced elsewhere. In doing so it will give you the option to remove all links to the soon-to-be-deleted item. This should satisfy your requirement.

Comment: This will only remove the references, not the actual referenced content items

Comment: I didn't see that any references from that item should be removed, it just says references to that item (which I'm assuming to be the deleted item) should be removed.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I'm sorry, didn't read it correctly.